# image saved in directory but does not preview

Tags: android, image, file, path, bitmap

my application takes photos and shows it in a gridview, but my problem is when I go to see it in the directory informed, it appears in the directory, but the image does not return,

Here is my code:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {

    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "relatorio" + timeStamp + "_";

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/VIEW REPORT/IMAGENS";
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
            Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));


    File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists())
        dir.mkdirs();


    File file = new File(dir, imageFileName);

    if( mCurrentPhotoPath != null ) {

        // write the document content
        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Toast.makeText(this, "PICTURE SAVE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "TRY AGAIN: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            dir      /* directory */
    );
```

And here is my device file explorer, could someone help me?

Note that its size is at 0B

[image]

Comment: You are creating empty image files. We can see that they are 0 bytes. Why are you creating empty files? Not needed at all.

Comment: `but the image does not return` What do you mean by that? Images usually dont return.

Comment: @blackapps I want to save it in a directory so I can get them by name, to appear in a gridview, to pull that specific directory